# How to fetch column value of selected row

Tags: php, mysql

Here is an excerpt from my code. I have removed `<table>`, `<tr>` statements and angular brackets  as this website seems to interpret it instead of showing them literally.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {    
    foreach($row AS $column) {   
           echo $column; 
    }

    echo '<a href=\"form.php\"> UPDATE </a>';
    echo '<a href=\"delete.php\"> DELETE </a>';
}
```

Now when user clicks on update, the value of first column of the selected row should be passed as querystring.

So, what should I add in a href statement ?

Comment: The `mysql`-extension is outdated, not maintained anymore and is marked as "deprecated" in PHP5.5. Use `PDO_MYSQL`, or `MySQLi`. http://php.net/en/mysql-connect (Its sad to see, that others still give advices in how to use `ext/mysql`...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysql_fetch_row()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) returns one row as numerically indexed array

```
$row=mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo "<a href=\"form.php?param=$row[0]\"> UPDATE </a>";
```

and do not use `mysql_` extension, try newer alternatives like [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))  
{    
  echo "<a href=\"form.php?id=.$row['id'].\"> UPDATE </a>";
  echo "<a href=\"delete.php?id=.$row['id'].\"> DELETE </a>";
}
```

Here id is the name of the database field id

Answer (score 0):

Reema, 
The below code is enough to fetch the first column

```
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
$first_column = $row[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `mysql_fetch_row`, you can use directly the indexed array returned by that function

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))  
{    
    $firstColumn = $row[0];
    echo "<a href='form.php?firstColumn=$firstColumn'> UPDATE </a>";
}
echo "<a href='delete.php'> DELETE </a>";
```

Assuming DELETE doesn't need the 1st column, and thus, the repetition either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {    
    $i = 0;
    $querystring = "";
    foreach($row AS $column) {   
          echo $column; 
          if($i == 0){
              $querystring = $column;             
           }
          $i++;
    }
    $querystring = "?q=".$querystring;  
    echo '<a href=\"form.php$querystring\" > UPDATE </a>';
    echo '<a href=\"delete.php$querystring\"> DELETE </a>';
}
```

I hope it will be helpful for you.

thanks